# Cordova not running the app on android

Tags: android, cordova

I recently just updated Cordova (on my Windows 10) and built the default hello world project. Usually, it works fine and runs on my phone, but now it just sort of builds and it just stops. It is not running on the phone, or not throwing any visible error. Here is a screenshot of what I get after executing `cordova run android --verbose`

[image]

And the process ends. I had been working on Cordova for past couple years, and haven't seen this type of behavior! Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Do you see your device when running `adb devices`?

Comment: Yes. But I see it's because of Cordova Android v7.1.1. When I remove and add v5.1.1, it loads without issue!

Comment: Another update, I can run the app on device from Android Studio. I don't know what's the issue with Cordova.